# How to slice lists in Python based on the length of its elements

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, slice

How to slice a list based on the length of its elements? 
For example, how do I turn

```
['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA']
```

into

```
['A','E],['LA'],['ELA']
```

Comment: What exactly is the condition you want to do this by?

Comment: Can you provide another more complex example? In case of a list like `['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA', 'B', 'CD']` what will the expected output be?

Comment: ['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA','ASD','AAAAAA']   --> ['A', 'E'],[ 'LA'],[ 'ELA','ASD'],['AAAAAA'] I want to create new lists based on the length of the strings

Comment: ['A', 'E','B'],[ 'LA','CD'],[ 'ELA']

Comment: Do you mean split the list into a set of lists where each list has strings of the same length? So in your example the 1 character strings in the list become their own list, the 2 character strings are put into another list, etc?

Comment: Thats's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l = ['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA', 'B', 'CD']

maximum = max([len(i) for i in l])
minimum = min([len(i) for i in l])
l = list([i for i in l if len(i)==s] for s in range(minimum, maximum+1))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'E', 'B'], ['LA', 'CD'], ['ELA']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
l = ['A', 'E', 'LA', 'ELA']
[list(g) for _,g in groupby(l,len)]
#Output:
#[['A', 'E'], ['LA'], ['ELA']]
```

Comment: `lambda x:len(x)` is the same as `len`. Drop the `lambda`.